# Windows Server: Uncheck "Automatically detect settings" in the internet connection settings for a new profile

Tags: default, windows-server-2012, internet-connection

I like to uncheck in the internet connection settings "Automatically detect settings", which is on by default. I tried to modify the default profile and I can verify that my script creates the correct entry, which is working on the current profile as well.

But as soon a new profile gets created, it is ignoring exactly this setting and sets it to the default.

Here is an excerpt of the script I am using (note: the default user hive was loaded before into xxtray:

> $key = 'HKLM:\xxtray\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'
>      $data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
>      if ($data.Length -eq 0) {
>        $keyorg = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections'
>        $data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections' -Name DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings
>      }
>      if ($data.length -eq 0) {
>        $data =   ([byte[]](0x46,0x00,0x00,0x00,06,0x00,0x00,0x00,01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
>        `0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2d,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x68,0x74,0x74,0x70,0x3a,0x2f,0x2f,0x65,`
>      ...
>        0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00))
>      }
>      if ($data.length -ne 0) {
>        $data[8] = 1
>        remove-itemproperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings
>        Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data
>      }

So, if I logon with a fresh profile, "Automatically detect settings" is on, byte 8 is set to 9, while it is set at the same time in the default user profile to 1

The question:
How can I override this behavior? It's not an option to place something as autologon to fix it.

Target OS is Windows Server 2008R2 and Windows Server 2012.

Thanks for help,
  Rolf.